# What does "but only because" mean?

Tags: meaning

I searched the online dictionaries but I cannot find the meaning of:

> but only because

So, Could you please explain it to me?

The text is here:

> The first time I saw King’s College, Cambridge, I didn’t think I was
>   dreaming, **but only because** my imagination had never produced anything
>   so grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Longman's](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/only) fourth definition of *only* might be of help here:

> **only** (*adverb*) used to say that something happens in one particular situation, or for one particular reason : *I’ll tell you, but only if you don’t tell anyone else*

So the author is saying: because her imagination had never seen anything so grand, she figured that she could not be dreaming.